# Python file is appending output, not overwriting

Tags: python, file, append

I am trying to read a file and write(overwrite) the file with another value within a loop.

```
a="1"
b="2"

for line in list:
    if os.path.exists(str(line.rstrip('\n'))):
        print line
        with open('/ifs/data/Scripts/currentNode.txt','r+') as nodeNumber:

            if nodeNumber.readline().rstrip('\n') == a:
                print "Origin 1"
                nodeNumber.write("2")
#                nodeNumber.close()

            elif nodeNumber.readline().rstrip('\n') == b:
                print "Origin 2"
                nodeNumber.write("1")
#                nodeNumber.close()

        time.sleep(5)
```

The code above only prints "Origin 1". The file currentNode.txt has the number 1 in it. For some reason it does not overwrite the file. If I do a output of the file, I see '1' but I if I open the file I see

```
1
2
```

Any ideas why the file isn't being overwritten? I put a sleep of 5 seconds thinking that the code is running to fast.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite because you opened the file as `r+`. Try opening with `w` to overwrite

Comment: I want to be able to read the file. w will overwrite what's in the file already. Basically when I run the script, if the file has 1: I want 2, if the file has 2:i want 1.

Comment: Note: avoid using `list` as a variable name, as this is also a Python function.

Comment: Then read the file, close it, figure out what to write, reopen, write

Comment: You also realise you are reading two lines if the first if evaluates to False not the same line twice? Also if line can be str.stripped then it is already a str

Comment: Well since the file only contains 1 line I believe this is okay. For future note, how would I reread the current line, do I just store the value in a variable?

Comment: Yes, simplest way is just to store it, you could seek but that is overkill for what you want

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can read and overwrite files in python using seek() and truncate():

```
a="1"
b="2"

f = open('/ifs/data/Scripts/currentNode.txt', 'r+')
contents = f.read()
f.seek(0)
f.truncate()
if a in contents:
    print "Origin 1"
    f.write(b)
elif b in contents:
    print "Origin 2"
    f.write(a)
f.close()
```